# What should I do if I have a question and found an _old_ answer?

Tags: support, status-completed, questions, answered-questions

I searched gis.se and found a *two year old* answer to a problem I have today.

But may be the *old* answer is not a good answer *today* because:

- technical changes in the tool (proposed in the old answer)
- license changes in the tool (proposed in the old answer)
- there are new tools (not exists 2 years ago)

What should I do to get an up-to-date answer?

Example:
I am looking for a (stand alone) tool to convert raster (e.g. tiff, jpg) to ECW. I found a [two years old question with an answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18369/how-to-convert-orthophotomap-to-ecw-file). The SDKs available from ERDAS are still read-only today. But perhaps there are other tools to convert to ECW today?

So the old answer is not *wrong* today. But there may exists *new/better* solutions for the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very much case by case advice but, I think what I would do is to try and edit the original Question, and possibly some or all of its answers, to make it explicitly clear that they apply up to a particular version or time.  This should be done carefully so that their content remains at least as relevant to the Q&A as it did when written.

I would then write a new Question that starts by referencing the original to ask whether the Answer remains the same today and/or at the current version.  If your new Question gets marked as a Duplicate then we will have both old and new pointers to the same valid Answer(s).  However, if not, then you should have an Answer that the situation has changed.  In the latter case I would recommend then flagging your new Q&A to be merged with the original.

Note that the "temporary" Q&A above is used to try and ensure that the new aspect to the original Q&A can be pulled out and dealt with rather than be swamped by the original details.